# Converting from Factor into Datetime object in R

Tags: datetime, r, timestamp

I want to convert my Factor that contains TimeStamps that got created in another application by a basic Java function into R Datetime objects. I use a German Windows Vista.

At the moment I tried two lines without success:

```
as.POSIXlt(as.character(Time), format="%b %d, %Y %T %r")
as.POSIXlt(Time, format="%b %d, %Y %T %r")
```

My dataset Time looks like:

```
structure(c(24L, 25L, 28L, 27L, 26L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
8L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 30L, 29L, 42L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 31L, 
33L, 32L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L), .Label = c("Apr 10, 2011 10:29:46 AM", 
"Apr 11, 2011 8:30:51 AM", "Apr 12, 2011 10:16:07 AM", "Apr 13, 2011 9:45:57 AM", 
"Apr 14, 2011 9:05:56 AM", "Apr 15, 2011 8:30:40 AM", "Apr 16, 2011 11:31:42 AM", 
"Apr 16, 2011 2:24:58 AM", "Apr 17, 2011 1:55:50 AM", "Apr 17, 2011 12:30:23 PM", 
"Apr 18, 2011 11:13:29 AM", "Apr 19, 2011 8:25:42 AM", "Apr 20, 2011 9:41:59 AM", 
"Apr 21, 2011 10:51:01 AM", "Apr 22, 2011 11:01:45 AM", "Apr 23, 2011 11:33:41 AM", 
"Apr 24, 2011 11:36:11 AM", "Apr 25, 2011 1:33:56 PM", "Apr 26, 2011 9:42:21 AM", 
"Apr 27, 2011 9:41:53 AM", "Apr 28, 2011 9:20:51 AM", "Apr 29, 2011 7:51:15 AM", 
"Apr 30, 2011 11:43:58 AM", "Apr 7, 2011 9:48:31 AM", "Apr 8, 2011 9:43:02 AM", 
"Apr 9, 2011 11:28:28 PM", "Apr 9, 2011 11:42:25 AM", "Apr 9, 2011 2:10:59 AM", 
"May 1, 2011 11:58:41 AM", "May 1, 2011 3:33:16 AM", "May 10, 2011 9:31:42 AM", 
"May 11, 2011 7:00:21 PM", "May 11, 2011 9:31:11 AM", "May 12, 2011 9:22:29 AM", 
"May 13, 2011 8:46:17 AM", "May 14, 2011 12:40:50 PM", "May 15, 2011 2:36:01 PM", 
"May 16, 2011 8:53:11 AM", "May 17, 2011 9:53:00 AM", "May 18, 2011 10:20:52 AM", 
"May 19, 2011 9:42:22 AM", "May 2, 2011 8:45:46 AM", "May 20, 2011 1:13:02 PM", 
"May 21, 2011 1:10:48 PM", "May 22, 2011 11:31:44 AM", "May 23, 2011 10:10:04 AM", 
"May 24, 2011 10:11:29 AM", "May 25, 2011 9:30:45 AM", "May 26, 2011 9:30:51 AM", 
"May 27, 2011 9:01:07 AM", "May 28, 2011 11:27:56 AM", "May 3, 2011 8:21:01 AM", 
"May 4, 2011 8:11:23 AM", "May 5, 2011 10:10:55 AM", "May 6, 2011 8:01:03 AM", 
"May 9, 2011 9:13:38 AM"), class = "factor")

sessionInfo()
R version 2.10.1 (2009-12-14) 
i386-pc-mingw32 

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=German_Germany.1252  LC_CTYPE=German_Germany.1252    LC_MONETARY=German_Germany.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                    LC_TIME=German_Germany.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_2.10.1
```

What's the problem?

Comment: It would be easier for us if you provided your dataset via `dput`.

Comment: @Joshua: I wasn't aware of dput. I added the data formatted that way.

Comment: What's the output of `sessionInfo()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think `%T` and `%r` are redundant.  Try this:

```
as.POSIXlt(as.character(Time), format="%b %d, %Y %r")
```

Also note (from `?strptime`) that some formatting characters not supported (for output) on Windows.

Comment: When I run that command it fills the first 28 numbers correctly but put NA's for the last 29-56

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure what would cause that.  My first attempt at an answer was riddled with errors (for one, it didn't account for AM/PM); does this new one work?

Comment: Strangly the new one doesn't work either. It seems to fail for all the May data.

Comment: Unable to reproduce errors. What version of R are you running?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that I have a German Windows Vista and Apr is the right abbreviation for the forth month in German while May isn't?

Comment: @Christian: yes, that would explain it.

Comment: Thank you. I got it working by editing the strings via *sub* to change the name of the month from English into German...

Comment: You might alternatively be able to fix the abbreviation mismatch problem by temporarily changing the locale to somewhere that abbreviates the months the same way as in your data file (see `?locales`)